# Override Magento 2 checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom proceed to checkout button Block and template file

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I see below configuration in Magento 2 layout at **`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`**. I created custom module and copied existing Link Block and link.phtml to the custom module folders.

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/methods.phtml">
    <container name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" label="Payment Methods After Checkout Button">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage/link.phtml" />
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\QuoteShortcutButtons" name="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" />
    </container>
</block>
```

I tried to override by adding one of the entry in **`app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`** but getting error 500 with first approach.

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
    <block class="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Onepage\CustomLink" name="custom.checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Vendor_Checkout::onepage/customlink.phtml">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I do see custom Block and phtml files in Commerce Bug tool but not seeing any code getting displayed from these files. Please shed some light since none of the approaches listed at also didn't help.

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom">
    <block class="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Onepage\CustomLink" name="custom.checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Vendor_Checkout::onepage/customlink.phtml">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Did you checked system.log and exception log?

Comment: Yes, no errors in system.log and exception.log files related to the cart page.

Comment: The error 500 was caused due to typo in variable in the custom Block that extended OOB Link Block. My code should add additional text/data around 'proceed to checkout' button based on customer group data but it's displaying same data for every customer even when a given customer is not in that group. I tried cacheable=false in the layout and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: @cnu I have been facing same issue unable to override could you please guide and advise me which is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

It's working with below changes to checkout_cart_index.xml and fixing issues with custom Block session code.

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block class="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Onepage\MyLink" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Vendor_Checkout::onepage/mylink.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```